# Большой буфер в асинхронных сокетах

Tags: c#, сокет

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Хочу использовать асинхронные сокеты для постоянной многопакетной передачи, с теорией разобрался, но вот беда: я не могу сообразить, как из буфера чтения перелить N байт в лист байтов, кроме как с помощью создания промежуточного массива и побайтовым копированием.

Мой код:

```
    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        var handler = state.WorkSocket;
        var bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            return;

        var tempBuf = new byte[bytesRead];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
            tempBuf[i] = state.Buffer[i];
        }
        state.BigBuffer.AddRange(tempBuf);

        // Do something...

        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallback, state);
    }
```

Хотелось бы услышать советы, как это дело оптимизировать.

PS: `List<byte> BigBuffer; BufferSize = 4096;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону **[MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)** в связке c [**BinaryReader**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)/[**BinaryWriter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)
Только не забывай, что MemoryStream работает с неуправляемым ресурсом, вывод - **используй Dispose()** *или* **using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(...))**